# Translation of this C# code to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework

I tried to translate following C# code

```
public static class ObjectSetExtensions
{
    public static void AddObjects<T>(this ObjectSet<T> objectSet, IEnumerable<T> objects)
    {
         foreach (var item in objects)
         {
             objectSet.AddObject(item);
         }
    }
}
```

to VB.NET:

```
Module ObjectSetExtensions
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Sub AddObjects(Of T)(ByVal objectSet As ObjectSet(Of T), ByVal objects As IEnumerable(Of T))
        For Each item In objects
            objectSet.AddObject(item)
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

But I getting an error that says:

> Type argument 'T' does not satisfy the 'Class' constraint for type parameter 'TEntity'.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C# version doesn't compile either, for the same reason. It should be:

```
public static void AddObjects<T>(this ObjectSet<T> objectSet,
                                 IEnumerable<T> objects)
    where T : class // Note this bit
{
     foreach (var item in objects)
     {
         objectSet.AddObject(item);
     }
}
```

And the VB version is:

```
<Extension> _
Public Sub AddObjects(Of T As Class)(ByVal objectSet As ObjectSet(Of T), _
                                     ByVal objects As IEnumerable(Of T))
    Dim local As T
    For Each local In objects
        objectSet.AddObject(local)
    Next
End Sub
```

Note how in the VB version the constraint is part of the type parameter declaration. For more details, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4xaz66w.aspx).

Comment: @Jared: Thanks, fixed. I didn't have it as part of a module in my sample code :)

Comment: In order to be a valid extension method in VB.Net it must be defined in a Module.  I'm not sure why they settled on that restriction since cross assembly VB.Net imports them from non-modules but it is what it is :)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are missing a constraint:

```
C#:
   where T : class

VB:
   (Of T as class)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your translation. That's the closest VB.NET equivalent of the provided C# code.

Based on the compilation error though the type `ObjectSet` is expecting the generic type parameter to be constrained to `class`. The original C# example doesn't have that, but if it did and was omitted from the question the VB.NET equivalent is the following.

```
Public Sub AddObjects(Of T As Class)(ByVal objectSet As ObjectSet(Of T) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Another conversion to VB.NET:

```
Public NotInheritable Class ObjectSetExtensions

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
    Public Shared Sub AddObjects(Of T)(objectSet As ObjectSet(Of T), objects As IEnumerable(Of T))
        For Each item As var In objects
            objectSet.AddObject(item)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```